# Fix permissions of the `/usr` directory

Tags: permissions, filesystem, chmod

I was trying to grant root access to the only user on my machine so I could edit folders and files on the main drive, however it seems I have crashed my system in trying to do so. I used `chmod - u` on the directory `/usr` and the GUI started disappearing. I tried rebooting but I can't even load the GUI. Is there an easy way I can fix this without having to reinstall the OS?

Comment: Could you please tell us exactly what command you entered?

Comment: The exact command I used was sudu chmod - u /usr/

Answer (score 1):

When you start your computer, press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. This will switch you to the console. Enter your username and password to continue.

Enter the command:

`sudo chmod 755 /usr`

You will be prompted for your password, enter it to continue. Then enter `sudo reboot` to restart the machine. This will restore the permissions of the `/usr` directory so your system should be back to normal.

Comment: Every time I try to use such chmod in console it says - bash: sudo: command not found.

Comment: This is because sudo is located under /usr/bin/sudo where you changed the permissions. The best way to fix this would be to boot from an Ubuntu boot disc and run the above commands on your root partition.